# String with both ' & "

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML element like this

```
<div id='test' onclick='window.location="http://example.com/";'></div>
```

I'm annoyed because I would like to put this into a string but I'm not able since this element use both `'` and `"` in its syntax.

How can I store such syntax into a string?

Comment: use \ backslash for double quotes

Comment: `var html = document.getElementById("test").outerHTML;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```js
var data = "<div id='test' onclick='window.location=\"http://example.com/\";'></div>"
alert(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just escape the strings with a `\`.

```
var myString = "<div id='test' onclick='window.location=\"http://example.com/\";'></div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

escape the ' or " with a backslash

```
var testString = '<div id=\'test\' onclick=\'window.location=\"http://example.com/\";\'></div>';
alert(testString);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use backslash \ for putting special character in string

for example for storing string "(double quotes) and '(single quotes) you can write

`var s="\"\'"`